# checking if substring exist in range

Tags: ios

In iOS,

```
Given an URL https://whateverthisisanurl.google.com/helloworld
```

If I want to test if google exists between the // and / whats is a good way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *mystring = @"https://whateverthisisanurl.google.com/helloworld";
NSString *regex = @".*?//.*?\\.google\\..*?/.*?";

NSPredicate *regextest = [NSPredicate
                         predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];

if ([regextest evaluateWithObject:mystring] == YES) {
    NSLog(@"Match!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"No match!");
}
```

Comment: also i dont think this would work because it would match https://imcool.com/theresgooglehere/helloworld/

Comment: So you want to match strings where google is not followed or preceded by anything?

Comment: then the regex would be this one @".*?//.*?\\.google\\..*?/.*?"